# Hash invert in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've got a hash of the format:

```
{key1 => [a, b, c], key2 => [d, e, f]}
```

and I want to end up with:

```
{ a => key1, b => key1, c => key1, d => key2 ... }
```

What's the easiest way of achieving this?

I'm using Ruby on Rails.

**UPDATE**

OK I managed to extract the real object from the server log, it is being pushed via AJAX.

```
  Parameters: {"status"=>{"1"=>["1", "14"], "2"=>["7", "12", "8", "13"]}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to print out an array so I can read it in order to experiment.

Comment: Still, what have you tried? `p array` prints stuff out.

Comment: Are you sure it's an array and not a hash? The way you're describing it is ambiguous.

Comment: why use weird pseudo-code? show as Ruby objects...

Comment: it's even simpler -- use Hash#inverse from FacetsOfRuby -- require 'facets'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hash = {:key1 => ["a", "b", "c"], :key2 => ["d", "e", "f"]}
```

first variant

```
hash.map{|k, v| v.map{|f| {f => k}}}.flatten
#=> [{"a"=>:key1}, {"b"=>:key1}, {"c"=>:key1}, {"d"=>:key2}, {"e"=>:key2}, {"f"=>:key2}]
```

or

```
hash.inject({}){|h, (k,v)| v.map{|f| h[f] = k}; h}
#=> {"a"=>:key1, "b"=>:key1, "c"=>:key1, "d"=>:key2, "e"=>:key2, "f"=>:key2}
```

**UPD**

ok, your hash is:

```
hash = {"status"=>{"1"=>["1", "14"], "2"=>["7", "12", "8", "13"]}}
hash["status"].inject({}){|h, (k,v)| v.map{|f| h[f] = k}; h}
#=> {"12"=>"2", "7"=>"2", "13"=>"2", "8"=>"2", "14"=>"1", "1"=>"1"}
```

Comment: This looks right but can't quite get it to work; I've updated the post now to show the actual object.

Comment: as we discussed in you previous question, fl00r, using inject when there is no need for it is IMHO not a good option. Also, you are using map but actually doing side-effects, which is confusing, each is better (well, "better", each is usually bad). Yeah, I know, I am a functional-bigot :-)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of other good answers. Just wanted to toss this one in too for Ruby 2.0 and 1.9.3:

```
hash = {apple: [1, 14], orange: [7, 12, 8, 13]}

Hash[hash.flat_map{ |k, v| v.map{ |i| [i, k] } }]
# => {1=>:apple, 14=>:apple, 7=>:orange, 12=>:orange, 8=>:orange, 13=>:orange}
```

This is leveraging: [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)

Also in these new versions there is [`Enumerable::each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) which is very similar to [`Enumerable::inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)/[`Enumerable::reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
hash.each_with_object(Hash.new){ |(k, v), inverse|
  v.each{ |e| inverse[e] = k }
}
```

Performing a quick [benchmark](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark_suite) (Ruby 2.0.0p0; 2012 Macbook Air) using an original hash with 100 keys, each with 100 distinct values:

```
Hash::[] w/ Enumerable#flat_map
            155.7 (±9.0%) i/s -        780 in   5.066286s
Enumerable#each_with_object w/ Enumerable#each
            199.7 (±21.0%) i/s -        940 in   5.068926s
```

Shows that the `each_with_object` variant is faster for that data set.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's guess. You say you have an array but I agree with Benoit that what you probably have is a hash. A functional approach:

```
 h = {:key1 => ["a", "b", "c"], :key2 => ["d", "e", "f"]}
 h.map { |k, vs| Hash[vs.map { |v| [v, k] }] }.inject(:merge)
 #=> {"a"=>:key1, "b"=>:key1, "c"=>:key1, "d"=>:key2, "e"=>:key2, "f"=>:key2}
```

Also:

```
 h.map { |k, vs| Hash[vs.product([k])] }.inject(:merge)
 #=> {"a"=>:key1, "b"=>:key1, "c"=>:key1, "d"=>:key2, "e"=>:key2, "f"=>:key2}
```

Comment: I keep getting "`odd number of arguments for Hash`". `Hash[vs...]` should be `Hash[ *vs.map { |v| [v, k] }.flatten ]` and the `inject(:merge)` is 1.9 only. Anyway, this just proves I should switch to 1.9 :-)

Comment: @undur_gongor, are you using <= 1.8.7 by any chance? it should work with ruby 1.8.7. You can also try "require backports" and see if it helps. Hash[] has accepted pairs for a long time now (the need of flattening was horrendous)

Comment: Yes (1.8.6). I keep confusing that. How do I fix the wrong comments now?

Comment: @undur_gongor: don't worry for old comments, people can see the whole conversation. You can delete them but then it seems I am talking alone :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the case where a value corresponds to more than one key, like "c" in this example...

```
{ :key1 => ["a", "b", "c"], :key2 => ["c", "d", "e"]}
```

...some of the other answers will not give the expected result. We will need the reversed hash to store the keys in arrays, like so:

```
{ "a" => [:key1], "b" => [:key1], "c" => [:key1, :key2], "d" => [:key2], "e" => [:key2] }
```

This should do the trick:

```
reverse = {}
hash.each{ |k,vs|
    vs.each{ |v|
        reverse[v] ||= []
        reverse[v] << k
    }
}
```

This was my use case, and I would have defined my problem much the same way as the OP (in fact, a search for a similar phrase got me here), so I suspect this answer may help other searchers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to reverse a hash formatted like this, the following may help you:

```
a = {:key1 => ["a", "b", "c"], :key2 => ["d", "e", "f"]}
a.inject({}) do |memo, (key, values)|
  values.each {|value| memo[value] = key }
  memo
end
```

this returns:

```
{"a"=>:key1, "b"=>:key1, "c"=>:key1, "d"=>:key2, "e"=>:key2, "f"=>:key2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_hash={}
hash = {"key1" => ['a', 'b', 'c'], "key2" => ['d','e','f']}
hash.each_pair{|key, val|val.each{|v| new_hash[v] = key }}
```

This gives

```
new_hash # {"a"=>"key1", "b"=>"key1", "c"=>"key1", "d"=>"key2", "e"=>"key2", "f"=>"key2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to correctly deal with duplicate values, then you should use the Hash#inverse
from Facets of Ruby**

**`Hash#inverse` preserves duplicate values**, 
e.g. it ensures that `hash.inverse.inverse == hash`

either:

- use Hash#inverse from here: http://www.unixgods.org/Ruby/invert_hash.html
- use Hash#inverse from FacetsOfRuby library 'facets'

usage like this:

```
require 'facets'

h = {:key1 => [:a, :b, :c], :key2 => [:d, :e, :f]}
 => {:key1=>[:a, :b, :c], :key2=>[:d, :e, :f]} 

h.inverse
 => {:a=>:key1, :b=>:key1, :c=>:key1, :d=>:key2, :e=>:key2, :f=>:key2}
```

The code looks like this:

```
# this doesn't looks quite as elegant as the other solutions here,
# but if you call inverse twice, it will preserve the elements of the original hash

# true inversion of Ruby Hash / preserves all elements in original hash
# e.g. hash.inverse.inverse ~ h

class Hash

  def inverse
    i = Hash.new
    self.each_pair{ |k,v|
      if (v.class == Array)
        v.each{ |x|
          i[x] = i.has_key?(x) ? [k,i[x]].flatten : k
        }
      else
        i[v] = i.has_key?(v) ? [k,i[v]].flatten : k
      end
    }
    return i
  end

end


h = {:key1 => [:a, :b, :c], :key2 => [:d, :e, :f]}
 => {:key1=>[:a, :b, :c], :key2=>[:d, :e, :f]} 

h.inverse
 => {:a=>:key1, :b=>:key1, :c=>:key1, :d=>:key2, :e=>:key2, :f=>:key2}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
arr = [{["k1"] => ["a", "b", "c"]}, {["k2"] => ["d", "e", "f"]}]

results_arr = []
arr.each do |hsh|
  hsh.values.flatten.each do |val|
    results_arr << { [val] => hsh.keys.first }···
  end
end


Result: [{["a"]=>["k1"]}, {["b"]=>["k1"]}, {["c"]=>["k1"]}, {["d"]=>["k2"]}, {["e"]=>["k2"]}, {["f"]=>["k2"]}]
```