# Inverting a hash: Making multiple hash keys from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to get a hash that has an array of values inverted such that the keys are now values. From an expression like this:

```
StackOverflow.transform({ 1 => ['A', 'E'] , 2 => ["B"]})
```

I'm trying to get this result:

```
{"A"=>1, "E"=>1, "B"=>2}
```

I have this:

```
class StackOverflow
  def self.transform(old)
    a = Hash[old.map { |k,v| v.product([k]) }.first]
  end
end
```

but the keys are all separated as individual keys (not grouped). It returns:

```
{"A"=>1, "E"=>1}
```

I'm also trying to downcase the keys, but I feel like after I figure out this inversion issue properly, I'll be able to (hopefully?) figure out the downcasing logic as well.

Comment: I prefer @Mark's use of `flat_map`, but another option is to replace `first` with `flatten(1)`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513730/hash-invert-in-ruby though it may be worth it to leave up since @MarkThomas has a better answer than any I saw in the previous question?

Comment: It's extremely similar @Sid, but unfortunately I couldn't find a good answer that made sense to me for my situation. Thanks for leaving it up. Unfortunate I got a down vote (probably for that) - but I assure people I search StackO as much as reasonably possible before posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close. You want to use `flat_map` instead of `first`.

```
class StackOverflow
  def self.transform(old)
    Hash[old.flat_map { |k,v| v.product([k]) }]
  end
end
```

You were using `first` to flatten the array.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
class StackOverflow
  def self.transform(old)
    val = nil
    old.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=val }) do |(k,v),h|
      val = k
      h.values_at(*v)
    end
  end
end

old = { 1=>['A', 'E'], 2=>['B'] }
StackOverflow.transform(old)
  #=> {"A"=>1, "E"=>1, "B"=>2}
```